# shell_exec syntax error. running in terminal directly is ok

Tags: php, bash

Having this command:

```
    $command = "diff -bBdH --ignore-all-space <(echo 'hi') <(echo 'hi1')";
    echo $command;
    $result = shell_exec($command);
```

On the screen I see:

```
    sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
    diff -bBdH --ignore-all-space <(echo 'hi') <(echo 'hi1')
```

If I copy-paste the second line from the console output into the terminal, the result would be correct. (Reproduced on another machine too).

I'm missing something dead simple here and can't see what it is.

---

besides, why is my output reversed?
I'm clearly echoing the command before executing it,
thus the syntax error of the shell should appear after the `shell_exec`

Comment: so if you use `diff -bBdH --ignore-all-space <(echo 'hi') <(echo 'hi')`, it will do what you want?

Comment: If I run that in `bash/zsh` - Yes. If I run this in `shell_exec` it would result in an error.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't find anything wrong with it. Maybe someone will show up who knows more about shell than me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is fine for Bash, but invalid for `sh`. Run it in Bash explicitly, or convert the Bashisms to classical Bourne shell (somewhat challenging, might need a temp file).

I don't know if PHP offers a way to specify which shell to use in `shell_exec`, but you can at least make `sh` run `bash` for you. The nested quoting gets a bit tricky, though.

```
shell_exec("bash -c 'diff -bBdH --ignore-all-space <(echo \"hi\") <(echo \"hi1\")'");
```

Output ordering between standard output and standard error is arbitrary; output buffering could cause an error message to be printed before a regular print although they were executed in a different order. Within a single stream, you can certainly rely on ordered output.

Comment: A short how-to for this would be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried quoting out your variables and putting quotes around the echo string?

```
$command = "diff -bBdH --ignore-all-space <(echo '" . $str1 ."') <(echo '" . $str2 . "')";
echo $command;
```

I believe it's always good practice to quote out variables. It makes it easy to read and helps resolve annoying errors.

Comment: Nope, but according to PHP's substitution principle this should had no effect. I'll try and report back.

Comment: As expected, absolutely no impact.

Comment: I'd even assume it fails way before the shell get's to the substituted string. Bash fails parsing the moment it gets to the first bracket. This wouldn't even work if you hardcode some text instead of $str1 and $str2;